# "Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" in elsif statement?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am writing an application (Shiny) that needs to check if you want to use specific data, for which you need to 1. check a box and 2. the date of the data you check should be less than 30 days ago. For this I wrote an `if (elseif)` statement

```
recent <- reactive({ 
  ifelse( as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.POSIXct(input$date) )) <= 30 && input$hist==TRUE, TRUE, FALSE )  
})
```

where `input$hist` is a checkbox on a UI which has default value `input$hist = FALSE` and if you check the `box = TRUE`. And `input$date` is also the input from the  UI which is a date. If you are not familiar with RShiny, the reactive just means that this value is automatically updated if something changes on the user interface.

I tried writing different if/else statements, with other variable values than *TRUE/FALSE* etc... If I only use the 30 days requirement my statement seems to work.

> Error: missing value where `TRUE/FALSE` needed

Comment: I suppose that the issue is due to the initialization phase of the input$hist or the input$date. try to add / change to:
`recent <- reactive({req(input$date);req(input$hist); ifelse( as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.POSIXct(input$date) )) <= 30 && input$hist==TRUE, TRUE, FALSE )  })`

Comment: Okay that works ( no errors are thrown up) with a slight modification. Now I have the problem that I use "recent=recent()" as an argument in one of my other functions. It works if recent() is TRUE but when recent() should be FALSE I get something weird (plots that should appear, disappear, no error?) but if I hardcode recent=FALSE the plots still appear. This points at the fact that recent() does not take on the value FALSE as it should? `recent <- reactive({ifelse( as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.POSIXct(input$date) )) <= 30 && req(input$hist)==TRUE, TRUE, FALSE ) })`

Comment: Writing `ifelse(condition, TRUE, FALSE)` is redundant redundancy. Just write `condition`. Likewise, instead of writing `something == TRUE`, just write `something`. Don’t repeat the obvious. This leaves `recent <- reactive(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.POSIXct(input$date))) <= 30 && input$hist)`.

Comment: @CFRedDemon at the next point you should use `req(recent())`.
Otherwise you should change your initial code to : `recent <- reactive({ifelse(!is.null(input$date) && !is.null(input$hist) && as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.POSIXct(input$date) )) <= 30 && input$hist, TRUE, FALSE) })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the initialization phase of the inputs. At this point `input$date` and `input$hist` are equal to `NULL`. The error is coming up because `NULL` is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. There are two ways to go:

1. Use the `req(input$x)` function. With that recent is going to be evaluated only after `input$x` is changed for the first time. In your case you have to use also req() at a second case.
2. Evaluate `recent` even if `input$date` and `input$hist` are `NULL`. i.e.:

```r
recent <- reactive(
             !is.null(input$date) &&
             !is.null(input$hist) && 
             as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.POSIXct(input$date) )) <= 30 &&
             input$hist
)
```

In case 2 you should be careful with your type of input. For example a text input has a default value of `''` thus is never `NULL`

Comment: Same comment as above: don’t write `ifelse(cond, TRUE, FALSE)`, it’s an anti-pattern.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot, and to Konrad, you are right. It seems bad practise indeed. I'll avoid it in the future, it's just that I'm used to writing in languages in which you can't do this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I do get your point on the question, but I do not get your point here. Could you please explain? Thank you!

Comment: @NpT The point is the same in both comments. This should be written omitting the `ifelse(…)` clutter (and the unnecessary braces): `reactive(!is.null(input$date) && !is.null(input$hist) &&  as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.POSIXct(input$date) )) <= 30 && input$hist)`.

Comment: Okay still not solved, above mentioned solution returns : `invalid 'y' type in 'x && y`. I don't know if this'll help, but that that input$hist = FALSE as "selected" (default value?) in the ui. This only happens when I check the box, so that input$hist = TRUE ?

Comment: `fluidRow( column(7,checkboxGroupInput("hist"," ",
                                  choices=c("Use historical files (if possible)"=TRUE),
                                  selected=FALSE)))` This is the code for the UI if any one of you are familiair with RShiny.

Comment: @CFRedDemon I think your issue is that choices should be a named list. i.e.: `choices=list("Use historical files (if possible)"=TRUE)`

@KonradRudolph Point taken! Thank you!

Comment: That could work, but I used a more suitable checkboxInput, which can be used if you only need a TRUE/FALSE output `fluidRow( column(7, checkboxInput("hist", label="Use historical files (if possible)", value = FALSE, width = NULL) ) ),` . Now my code works perfectly fine! Thanks for the help everyone.